# angular $resource PATCH request with body payload

Tags: angularjs, resources, patch

Is it possible to send a PATCH request with a complex object in the request body? The following works fine but it sends the object as url parameters not in the request body..

```
  //region - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - update with PATCH
        patch: function(url, obj, funcSuccess){

            // server call
            var resP =  resource(appConfigSvc.apiBaseUrl + url, obj, {
                'update': {
                    method:'PATCH',
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                }
            });
            var defer = q.defer();
            resP.update(
                function(data) {
                    defer.resolve(data);
                    if(funcSuccess){
                        funcSuccess(data);
                    }
                },
                function(response) {
                    //responseHandlerSvc.handleResponse(response);
                    defer.reject(response);
                });
            return defer.promise;
        },
        //endregion
```

WebApi doesn't have a problem accepting patch request body. Postman also allows sending patch requests with body. The only problem is Angular $resource.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115771/angularjs-upload-files-using-resource-solution) out. Although patch and put methods fail to send payload (on working with post)

Comment: Thanks. I have decided to stop using $resource. 
Now, I only use $http and it has no problem sending payloads with a patch request.

Answer (score 0):

I created this method to send any request I need using $http. Nice and simple..

```
function send(method, url, obj, params){

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var promise = http(
        {
            method:method,
            url: url,
            data:obj,
            headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Accept':'application/json'},
            params:params
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function(msg, code) {
            deferred.reject(msg);
        });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```