# AngularJS $resource is encoding entire object into URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-resource, angular-http

I'm using Angular 1.4.8 with Angular UI and TypeScript.  My models are defined as such:

```
export interface IBatch extends ng.resource.IResource<IBatch> {
    id: Number;
    ...
}

export interface IBatchResource extends ng.resource.IResourceClass<IBatch> {
    snapshot(batch: IBatch);
}
```

I setup my `Batch` resource with a custom HTTP verb `TAKE-SNAPSHOT`, which returns either a `200 OK` or a `404 NOT FOUND`:

```
var paramDefaults = {
    id: '@id'
};

var actions = {
    'snapshot': { method: 'TAKE-SNAPSHOT' }
};

return <IBatchResource> this.$resource('/api/batches/:id', paramDefaults, actions);
```

This lets me take a snapshot of a particular Batch.  The *only* parameter for this API call is the batch Id.  However, `$resource` is encoding the *entire* `Batch` object into the query string (the actual string is over 1000 characters long, shortened for brevity):

> localhost:15000/api/batches/4?$originalData=%7B%22id%22:4,%22createdDateUtc%22:%222015-12-...

How do I make `$resource` direct the request to `localhost:15000/api/batches/4`?

Comment: The only way I can think of is a POST as multipart/form-data, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33350954/2535335

Comment: After reading [ngResource source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngResource/resource.js#L577) it seems that it's not possible as `hasBody` is constrainted to `POST/PUT/PATCH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed a workaround:

```
var paramDefaults = {
    id: '@id'
};

var actions = {
    'snapshot': <ActionDescriptor>{ method: 'TAKE-SNAPSHOT' }
};

var retval = <IBatchResource> this.$resource('/api/batches/:id', paramDefaults, actions);

/*
 * Passing in the object results in serializing the entire Batch into the URL query string.
 * Instead, we only want to pass the ID.
 */
var oldSnapshotFn = retval.snapshot;
retval.snapshot = (batch: IBatch) => oldSnapshotFn(<any>{id: batch.id });
return retval;
```