# how to upload a file using $resource in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to post form data using $resource, before I was using $http as following :

```
upload : function(file){
          let fd = new FormData();
          fd.append('file', file);
          $http.post('http://localhost:8080/fileUpload', fd, {
              transformRequest: angular.identity,
              headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
            })
            .success(function(){
            })
            .error(function(){
            });
        }
```

and now I want to use $resource instead, and this is what I tried to do but it didn't work :

```
upload : function(file){
          let fd = new FormData();
          fd.append('file', file);
          $resource('http://localhost:8080/fileUpload/:id',fd, {
            create: {
              method: "POST",
              transformRequest: angular.identity,
              headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
            }
          });
        }
```

## Edit (Solution) :

From this post [AngularJS: Upload files using $resource (solution)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115771/angularjs-upload-files-using-resource-solution) there was two solutions the first one which was pointed out by @juandemarco was to configure the `$http` service but this will transform each and every request made by AngularJS, so the second one which was pointed out by @timetowonder was a better solution since I need to define this behavior only for those $resources that actually need it, so I tried as following :

**in my controller :**

```
var fd = new FormData();
      fd.append('identityDocUpload', $scope.identityDocUpload);
      fileUploadService.create({}, fd).$promise.then(function (res) {
        console.log('success');
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('err');
      });
```

**my service :**

```
app
  .factory('fileUploadService', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:8080/fileUpload/:id', { id: "@id" }, {
      create: {
        method: "POST",
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: so your `identityDocUpload` is what holds the file?  Did you have to implement listen to `change` with a directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out here, you CAN do it the way explained, but you'll have some browser version limitation. 
In the case below, he's uploading an image.

[AngularJS: Upload files using $resource (solution)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115771/angularjs-upload-files-using-resource-solution)